# Why do windows generally open to the outside in Ireland but not in the rest of continental Europe?

Tags: windows

See title.

I see the reason for having it outside is being able to always have them open for ventilation. Since Ireland has a mild but humid climate.

Opening to the inside inteferes with having plants on the window sills.

Why not have a combination of both?

Comment: I live on the other side of the pond so I am not sure. Could it be a building code issue? Here in the U.S. some States have very strict codes on windows and skylights causing them to be 2X or 3X the cost of those avaiable in other areas. Some multi level structures the windows are not allowed to open on the upper floors. Can you contact the building inspectors and ask for your area?

Comment: Ireland isn't part of continental Europe, hence "rest of continental Europe" makes no sense.

Comment: I always thought it was islanders who invented sliding windows to cope with constant winds from the sea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found some details about use and locale usage of window directions and some arguments for both choices:

http://www.luxal.co.uk/inward-and-outward-opening-windows/

Summing up the claims by Frank Tate:

The direction is more seperated between northern (Scandinavian, UK) versus central and southern countries (Pt, Es, Fr, De, It, ...).

Both solutions have unique advantages in regard to climate and handling:

- Appearence: Inward opening windows are hiding themself behind the frame when they are open.
- Cleaning and Installation: Inward opening windows are same easy to clean from inside and outside. For modern outward opening windows there seem to be solutions as well.
- Flowerpot: Inward opening windows are best decorated from outside, while outwards opening windows are best decorated from inside.
- Shutters: For inward opening windows external shutters can be used. They are providing much better isolation for radiating heat than internal shutters. They also enable ventilation while keeping radiation heat outside.
- Weather: Outwards windows tend to be more resilant to wind and rain, while they have to be secured when open at stormy weather.
- Security: Outwards windows can be more secure.

Comment: Link-only answers are not considered valuable as links can die at any time. Please include the relevant information here, in your post, with appropriate attribution.

Comment: +1 for this info. Where I live we have strong winds, but windows open outward because we can “scoop” the wind up to cool our homes. All the sashes have catches that allow the sash to be fixed...no free movement.

Answer (score 2):

Here in Italy there's an historic reason: doors and windows opens inside because there was a tax on 'public soil usage' and a door or a window opening inside wasn't subjected to it. Anyway nowadays most have shutters on the outside and the glazing on the inside so window opens in both directions.

Comment: +1 for that info. Any window along a walkway would need to be careful not to open over a sidewalk that a person could walk into.

Answer (score 1):

In Baltic, we have that for safety reasons...

When windows open inside that means the strong wind can't "wobble" them back and forth, eventually loosing the loops, which eventually can result window to fall off.

Considering that most of the houses are "Communist houses" (usually 9 story houses, containing 150+ flats) you'd had way too high risk of getting killed by falling windows IF they were opening outside.

"Communist House" 602 series (most common type) example:

[image: Image Source: Riga.lv]